# iptables logging performance

Tags: linux, iptables

Need to understand the traffic between different VMs (hunderds of them) and planning to use iptables logging to create log of the new connections (both inbound and outbound). A script can parse the log and get the source/destination IP and ports. But then I need to log for several days (may be a week) to get the full picture of all possible connections. Planning to roll the log file every hour but concern is performance, since this needs to be done in LIVE servers. Will the iptables logging add significant overhead? I'm new to Linux and your inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load depends mostly on the number of connections that need to be logged. It's pretty small per-connection, but if there's a server that needs to handle a huge rate of connections, it can add up.

`iptables`puts the log messages into the kernel message buffer (which is viewable with the `dmesg` command). The rest of the job is usually handled by your syslog daemon.

If it's the traditional `syslogd`/`klogd` pair, they will consume whatever amount of system resources is needed to get the messages to the log files and/or remote log destinations, as configured.

But in many modern distributions, `rsyslogd` is used, and it can rate-limit messages - and in many distributions, this limit level is set quite low for iptables logging. It seems that the default rate is designed to protect old, low-power servers, so you can safely increase the limit - but you must remember to do that.

If you're running Java software, they tend to use a significant number of network sockets for local communications: you may want to set your logging rules carefully to not log those, to minimize the amount of data that needs to be logged at the source. Likewise, if you know there are large amounts of connections you already understand or don't care about, you may wish to exclude them from logging to keep the total amount of data manageable.

Make sure you create only one log message per connection if possible. Logging *all* incoming & outgoing packets would generate a significant extra load for sure.

Also don't assume that after a week of logging you'll know everything there is to know: depending on your site, there might be some connections that only happen at end-of-month, or perhaps quarterly.